# discord.js auto role from status activity

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, status

I'm coding a bot for my server and I want the bot to read the status of all members and give them a particular role if they have the vanity link. I've made this code from scratch and it seems to not work.
Here is the code :

```
client.on('presenceUpdate', async (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
  const role = newPresence.guild.roles.cache.get("844047538797281310");
  const member = newPresence.member


  if (member.user.presence.activities[0]?state.includes( ".gg/moonxile" || "discord.gg/moonxile" )) {
    return newPresence.member.roles.add(role)
  } else {
    if(member.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
      newPresence.member.roles.remove(role)
    }
  }
})
```

I'm sort of new to coding and I'm not able to tell where I've gone wrong

Comment: `includes( ".gg/moonxile" || "discord.gg/moonxile" )` this is not how you check if it includes. You need to individually check if it includes or not. Eg :`..state.includes(" link") || ..state.includes("link")`.

Comment: oh ok i'll update that

Comment: it shows this error
```if (member.user.presence.activities[0]?state.includes(".gg/moonxile") || member.user.presence.activities[0]?state.includes("discord.gg/moonxile")) {
                                                                                                                                                   ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'```

Comment: Is that question mark supposed to be there?

Comment: hmm i actually don't know. I tried removing it but didn't make a change either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first [.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes?retiredLocale=vi) js method is not support condition in it
And member.user.presence.activities is array of [activity](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Activity) and states is it's property so the code should be look like

```js
client.on('presenceUpdate', async (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    const role = newPresence.guild.roles.cache.get("844047538797281310");
    const member = newPresence.member
    const activities = member.user.presence.activities[0];
  
    if (activities && (activities.state.includes( ".gg/moonxile" ) || activities.state.includes("discord.gg/moonxile" ))) {
      return newPresence.member.roles.add(role)
    } else {
      if(member.roles.cache.get(role.id)) {
        newPresence.member.roles.remove(role)
      }
    }
})
```

Comment: The code works but it actually loops through an error and doesn't add the role to the user. This is the [error](https://pastebin.com/6zYMpyKq) which was looped 104 times

Comment: I have edited my solution try. but seem there is no loop here even id is not defined

Comment: yes thanks a lot!! it works perfectly now. it does show the error but doesn't loop.

Comment: the bot doesn't remove the role if a user already has it T_T

Comment: So can i know the remaining errors? It it's done can you mark it's a result

Comment: Do it add a role success please check it.

Comment: yes it adds role and removes. but sometimes it doesn't remove

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232621/discussion-between-hellcatvn-and-darshan-b).